# Array method printing is almost right, just one value is off which I'm not sure why

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, output

So I'm trying to get an array to be passed into a separate method and then return a new sized array but the program has just one incorrect value. For example, I have an array

```
int [] myInches = {89,12,33,7,72,42,76,49,69,85,61,23};
```

That I'm trying to pass into my createLowerArray method

```
 public static int [] createLowerArray(int maxParam, int [] myInchesParam) {
    int [] betterInches = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myInchesParam.length; i++) {
        if (myInchesParam[i] < maxParam) {
            count++;
        }
        betterInches = new int [count];
        int newCount = 0;
        for (int q = 0; q < betterInches.length; q++) {
            if (myInchesParam[newCount] < maxParam) {
                betterInches[q] = myInchesParam[newCount];
            }
            newCount++;
        }
    }
    return betterInches;
}
```

With maxParam just being whatever the user inputs. So let's say they put in 40, the second method will see that only 4 elements, (12,33,7, and 23) are less than 40 and create an array of length 4 with position 0 being 12, [1] = 33, [2] = 7, and [3] = 23, but for some reason my program makes it so. Position 0 in the new array is 0, [1] = 12, [2] = 33, and [3] = 7. the length is correct but the values aren't in the right positions. I got help with this earlier and thought I had it, it feels bad to be back so fast but I just can't seem to figure it out. Thank you to anyone who helps. I know this can be made easier with lists, streams and the like but I need practice with loops.

Expected output should be

```
int length = 4
[0] = 12
[1] = 33
[2] = 7
[3] = 23
```

Current output is

```
int length = 4
[0] = 0
[1] = 12
[2] = 33
[3] = 7
```

Comment: Please can you just show the expected and actual output, rather than trying to describe it?

Comment: By the way, I doubt you actually want to create a new `betterInches` on each loop iteration: everything in the loop from `betterInches = new int [count];` downwards should probably be outside the loop.

Comment: And `newCount++` should be inside the if.

Comment: Just edited the question with expected and current output, I really gotta do that more sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is here:

```
    for (int q = 0; q < betterInches.length; q++) {
        if (myInchesParam[newCount] < maxParam) {
            betterInches[q] = myInchesParam[newCount];
        }
        newCount++;
    }
```

You are *always* incrementing `newCount`, even if you didn't copy the value. Also, you need to loop over `myInchesParam`, not `betterInches`:

```
    for (int j = 0, q = 0; j < myInchesParam.length; j++) {
        if (myInchesParam[j] < maxParam) {
            betterInches[q] = myInchesParam[j];
            q++;
        }
    }
```

---

Additionally, you are doing a lot more work than necessary - your current code is quadratic in the size of the input array. You create the new `betterInches` array on each iteration of the outer loop, and then discard that and create it again on the next iteration.

Move the inner loop out of the outer loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myInchesParam.length; i++) {
    if (myInchesParam[i] < maxParam) {
        count++;
    }
}

betterInches = new int [count];
for (int i = 0, q = 0; i < myInchesParam.length; i++) {
    if (myInchesParam[i] < maxParam) {
        betterInches[q++] = myInchesParam[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but for some reason it turns all the values to position elements to 0 when I do that

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Actually you are not iterating on whole array for getting your params. changed second loop to this.

```
 int newCount = 0;
 for (int q = 0; q < myInchesParam.length; q++) {
     if (myInchesParam[q] < maxParam) {
         betterInches[newCount] = myInchesParam[q];
         newCount++;
     }

 }
```

seprate first loop and second loop. your second loop is inside the first loop. take a look on code below.

```
public static int [] createLowerArray(int maxParam, int [] myInchesParam) {
    int [] betterInches = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};// Dont need to initialize
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myInchesParam.length; i++) {
        if (myInchesParam[i] < maxParam) {
            count++;
        }
    } // First loop end here

    betterInches = new int [count];
    int newCount = 0;
    for (int q = 0; q < myInchesParam.length; q++) {
       if (myInchesParam[q] < maxParam) {
          betterInches[newCount] = myInchesParam[q];
          newCount++;
       }

    } // Second Loop ends heer

    return betterInches;
}
```

Comment: I put the newCount++; inside the if loop now and all my element positions are 0 for some reason.

Comment: Thank you once again but now it gives me an ArrayIndexoutofBoundsException error on the "betterInches[newCount] = myInchesParam[q];" line. I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int q = 0; q < betterInches.length; q++) {
        if (myInchesParam[q] < maxParam) {
            betterInches[newCount] = myInchesParam[q];
            newCount++;
           }      
    }
```